# Get button in HTML on home screen to route to a page labelled "about"

Tags: html, typescript, function, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the button when clicked on to go to a second page in the app but I cannot figure out how to do so. (I am new to Ionic but have been stuck on this for hours)

This is the HTML in home.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      The God Taco
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="gotoAbout()">
        About
        <ion-icon name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

This is the code in home.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AboutPage } from './about.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

gotoAbout() {
  this.navCtrl.push('AboutPage');
}
```

Also the folders look like this:
[image: folder pathway]![1]
[link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Dzk.jpg

ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(4,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module './about.page'.
[ng]     src/app/home/home.page.ts(12,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'gotoAbout'.

When the recompiling this is the error in the terminal.

Comment: I assume you are using Ionic 3, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Ionic 4` :

You can also redirect it directly in html file :

```
<ion-button routerLink="/AboutPage"><ion-button>
```

or another way :

[visit this link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573043/how-to-navigate-between-pages-in-ionic-4-5/57575115#57575115)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ionic 4:

`constuctor(private router: Router){}`

```
goToAbout(){ 
   this.router.navigate(['/AboutPage']);
}
```

Where `AboutPage` should be the name of the page as defined by the `path` label in your `app-routing.module.ts`